# jquery function not being called on div load

Tags: jquery, function

I have built a simple word cloud generator function which get's triggered when the div the word cloud should display in has loaded.

This function is used on two different pages of my web app.

Here is the jquery which is saved in a file called **keywords.js**

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus id tincidunt purus. Maecenas mi erat, gravida eget nisl vel, ultricies vehicula leo.";
var word_list = text.split(/\W+/);
var used;

function populateKeywordCloud(wordCount, selector) {
for (i = 0; i < wordCount ; i++) {
    used = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    $(selector + ' #keyword_cloud .dataBoxContent').append('<span class="cloud_' + used + '" title="Keyword used ' + used + ' times" ">' + word_list[i] + '</span> ');
}
}

$('.summary_page').ready(function () {
populateKeywordCloud(30, '.summary_page');
});
```

HTML:

```
<section class="dataBox" id="keyword_cloud">
        <header class="dataBoxHeader">
            <a href="keyword_cloud.html" title="View more">Keyword Cloud <img src="img/view_more.svg" height="12" title="View more" class="view_more" /></a>
            <div class="minimise">
                <img src="img/minimise.svg" title="Minimise section" class="minIcon" width="15" height="15" onclick="toggleDataBox('keyword_cloud')" />
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="dataBoxContent">                
        </div>
        <a href="keyword_cloud.html" class="view_more_summaryP" title="Click for more information">View more</a>
</section>
```

However for some reason the populateKeywordCloud() function won't run. I have done some debugging and see this method never gets fired.

But strangely when I place the following code in another .js file in this project the function does get triggered and my word cloud gets displayed.

```
$('.summary_page').ready(function () {
populateKeywordCloud(30, '.summary_page');
});
```

This is very strange to me. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: try to debug in console, and make sure your javascript not conflict with other script..

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/ready/ "A function to execute after the DOM is ready."

You cannot use ready that way. .ready() is only used to know when the DOM is loaded.

$(document).ready(function); is the way to go. ( when all the DOM is loaded ) WITHOUT SELECTORS

However, I don't know why the function get triggered when it is in another file. Maybe the selector messes something up.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting everyone's time! I was calling another .js function that was missing from the page I called the function from.

All is working fine now.